# Expressjs routing from angularjs routes

Tags: angularjs, express

I am having issues with calling the routes from my front end to the backend.

I am using angularjs $state on the client so an example url is

http://localhost:1234/areas/customer/edit/56e2f6345968f8b812052694

However when i call this route on the server sideusing $resouce query as below it calls the incorrect server side route.

My factory contains a method which uses $resource to call the server side

```
 getCustomerByID: function(id, callback){
          var cb = callback || angular.noop;

          return Customer.query(id, function(success){
            return cb(success);
          }, function(error){
            return cb(error);
          }).$promise;
        }
```

Customer is the service as below

```
angular.module('xxx')
  .factory('Customer', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/customer/:id/:controller', { id: '@_id' })
  });
```

The server routes are as follows for the GET

```
router.get('/', controller.index);
router.get('/:id', controller.show);
```

I need to hit the route with the id but it seems to hit the first one

Any ideas what it could be

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Routes are processed in order, swap the following routes around:

```
router.get('/', controller.index);
router.get('/:id', controller.show);
```

To this:

```
router.get('/:id', controller.show);
router.get('/', controller.index);
```

This happens because the a request like `/api/customer/:id/` Will also just match `/api/customer`, hence why it catches on the first route.

Comment: Yeah tried that but no joy shouldn't have to restart grunt server?

Comment: Yes, try restarting -  the routes above should work.

Comment: Still no joy. When passing the id to the query i have tried passing it as an array [{id: id}] but thats not working either

Comment: I don't think the issue is with Express then, final thing (for Express) to check - are you calling `next()` in your `controller.show` route/action? If so, this will pass the request to the next route in the chain. I don't have much knowledge of angular - are you referencing `:controller` anywhere? Also, have you checked in your networking tab (browser console) that the AJAX request is hitting the correct URL?

Comment: got it hitting now but had to override the query method within the client side as so query: { method: "GET", isArray: false }. So its hitting the server side now but doesnt like it as its not an array. Its more of an angularjs issue now it seems

Comment: I used get instead of query as the mean stack returns json from the server side. So did not want to break other hits to that controller method. That did the trick